# Possible to save changes to an element in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

If I make a change using the inspect element tool in Chrome, is there any script or extension that would make it so that the changes were remembered if I was to revisit that page?

Thanks.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it answered your question. This helps other users who may have the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of changes?

You can modify the User Stylesheet ([`UserDataDir`](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)`\User StyleSheets\Custom.css`) to make client-side modifications to a page’s style that will be remembered whenever you visit a page (though you have to be specific since the changes could also affect other sites), but there is no way to modify pages (i.e., structure, content) stored on external servers.

That’s not to say that an extension couldn’t theoretically be made to do this. It is certainly possible for an extension to make dynamic, client-side changes to a page’s structure and content after it has loaded, but they usually only make specific changes like removing ads (there are [HTML *editors*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pageedit/ebkclgoaabaibghklgknnjdemknjaeic), but they are not quite what you are looking for; they are really just editors). I have [yet to see one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/customize%20pages) that is flexible enough that can let you make arbitrary changes, save them, and have them re-applied each time the page is loaded. (Blast it! You just gave me an idea for yet another new project that I don’t have time for… ಠ_ಠ)

Comment: Sadly Google has removed all support for user stylesheets as of v.33, so this no longer works. You can try it with a stylesheet extension (assuming you’re willing to take the hit of CPU and memory overhead of yet another extension), but it won’t be able to affect Chrome’s internal pages, so you won’t be able to [customize the NTP](http://superuser.com/questions/304494/) or fix their [horrible UI designs](http://superuser.com/questions/630027/). On the bright side, there’s no longer any reason to bother with the project; the only Chrome-related project now is migrating away from it.